# How to resolve button element bug caused by repeating dot background-image on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button

Button element doesn't back to default from hover on IE edge, 11, and 10.

```css
.parent {
    background-color: #000;
}
.child {
    width:100vw;
    height: 200vh;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAQAAADYv8WvAAAADUlEQVQIHWP4n8YAAQAMMQFm8OKYGAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    background-size: 2px;
}
button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <button>HOVER ME</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Occurrence condition are bellow.
- Add background-image of repeating dot image including alpha channel.
- Put a button element into the above element.

I could fix this by edit background-size property to 3px.
But I want to know how to fix without edit background-size.

Is there any solution?

Comment: It could possibly be that they don't have support for `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAQAAADYv8WvAAAADUlEQVQIHWP4n8YAAQAMMQFm8OKYGAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: I think IE8 or greater support Data URIs.  
Please see this. https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri